# What does this equation mean and what are the parameters?

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory

I was reading an article about gravitons and I saw these equations that i don’t know what do they mean. I was wondering if you could help me out.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These equations have nothing to do with gravitons, gravity, or curved spacetime.

Instead, they represent the *flat*-spacetime theory of a complex-valued [scalar field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_field) $\phi$, describing particles of spin $0$ with mass $m$ and charge $e$, interacting with an [electromagnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_field) described by the [four-potential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_four-potential) $A^\mu$, describing spin-$1$ photons. $D_\mu$ is called a [gauge-covariant derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_covariant_derivative). $\mathcal{L}$ is the [Lagrangian density](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_(field_theory)) for this theory.

The theory is known as “[scalar quantum electrodynamics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_electrodynamics)”. The Lagrangian density shown leaves out some important parts of the theory, such as the dynamics of the EM field and a possible interaction of the scalar field with itself.